# Selenium 3.7.1 webdriver Error: Timed out waiting for driver server to start. Windows only

Tags: windows, selenium, webdriver, nightwatch.js

I have the following error on Windows 7 but not a a mac. It is started by nightwatch. Any ideas?

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  17228
[Test] Test Suite
=============================
Running:  TestWithSettingSearchValue
Error retrieving a new session from the selenium server
Connection refused! Is selenium server started?
{ value:
   { stacktrace: 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.\nBuild info: version: \'3.7.1\', revision: \'8a0099a\', time: \'2017-11-06T21:07:36.161Z\'\nSystem info: host: \'W7D0596\', ip: \'172.21.1.54\', os.name: \'Windows 7\', os.arch: \'amd64\', os.version: \'6.1\', java.version: \'1.8.0_91\'\nDriver info: driver.version: unknown\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:192)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:178)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:207)\r\n\tat org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11(ActiveSessionFactory.java:167)\r\n\tat
```

Our package.json

```
{
  "name": "nightwatch",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "nightwatch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chromedriver": "^2.33.2",
    "nightwatch": "^0.9.16",
    "selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^3.7.1"
  }
}
```

nightwatch:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-3.7.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://127.0.0.1:3000/",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Update the Question with your code trials please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the file extension for it to work on windows. Update your config and add `.exe` to the chromedriver path and it should start working.

```
"cli_args" : {
    "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe"
}
```

Comment: There is no .exe in this npm package

Comment: Yes there is. It is under the `lib\chromedriver` directory.

Comment: ah, it only does that if your on windows, im on a mac